# SBS 2008 Script to connect - disconnect backup disk?

Tags: backup, scripting, windows-sbs-2008

I want to be able to leave multiple external drives connected to an SBS 2008 server and select which drive is used as a target for the backup without physically connecting/disconnecting the drive.

Windows doesn't support this and my testing confirms that if 2 drives are connected there is little to no rotation between the target drives, the backup will run to the last drive it used if it is connected.  Anyone have a script that will disconnect and reconnect a physical drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Windows sym links at all really, but that might be what you're after.

With say three drives attached;

- create a symbolic link to one using mklink
- run the backup so the link is the destination
- have a daily script that deletes and remakes the link pointing to the next drive in rotation